# Remove all punctuation except comma in a regular expression in awk

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I have a variable

```
 local= "[ 'service center','New' ]"
```

I have used the following awk code to remove the square braces and single quotes,

```
  local=gensub(/[\[\]']+/, "", "g", local);
  local=gensub(/[^,[:punct:][:space:]]/, "", "g", local);
```

Expected O/P is

```
local = "service center,New"
```

The code I wrote is not working

Comment: do you want to get rid of the space or keep the space?

Comment: I want to get rid of the spaces too, I have updated my question

Comment: spaces (`[:blank:]` representing spaces and tabs) or space-characters (`[:space:]` representing spaces, tabs, formfeeds, ..., to name a few)

Comment: Try what I wrote below, should do the trick

Comment: Your question is now completely changed and not in line anymore with the original statement of the title.

Comment: @kvantour  OP did this kind of thing two times already, and is not willing to change.

Answer (score 1):

**Original question:** _How do I select all punctuation, except <comma> with a regular expression.

The group `[:punct]` is defined as *characters that are not letters, digits, control characters, or space characters*.

```
[:punct] = [^[:alnum:][:cntrl:][:space:]]
```

So, what you want is *characters that are not letters, digits, control characters, space characters or the <comma>-character*.

```
[^[:alnum:][:cntrl:][:space:],]
```

**After OP's edit:**

The following should do the requested:

```
gsub(/(^[^[:alnum:],]*|[^[:alnum:],[:blank:]]|[^[:alnum:],]*$)/, "", local)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, I was doing it wrong before, Is it any way I could skip single spaces too,Could you please see my updated O/P

Comment: @mittu  You should accept this answer instead of say thanks and keep changing your question. Please read [someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  and  [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).